# How do I calculate the number of chars in a string (if not all the space is taken)

Tags: c, string, char, malloc

I have this piece of code:

```
char* input = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
scanf("%s", input);        //let's say that the number of chars in "%s" is 5
```

How do I calculate how many chars I typed in (5)? I tried by playing around with sizeof(), but couldn't find a solution.

Edit (better explanation): the input variable can host up to 100 chars, but let's say I type in the terminal 'abcde': then it hosts only 5 chars, the other 95 are not taken. I want to calculate that '5'.

Comment: [`strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen)

Comment: Maybe the `strlen()` function?

Comment: Thanks for the strlen() mention, I could only think about allocated space and such, I totally forgot about that function. Maybe you could post it as an answer so that I can upvote it and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the null terminator.

```
int i = 0;
while(input[i] != 0) {
    ++i;
}
//i marks the spot
```

But yeah, strlen() does a better job, since it has some improved/optimized searching, since it uses word(16/32/64? bit) compare and stuff.

Comment: You *could* do it with a `for` loop, but a call to `strlen()` is easier both to write and to read.

Comment: nor `int` but `size_t`